# Combing jQuery Isotope filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope

Can anyone help me with combing jQuery Isotope filters please.  In the example (CodePen Link) there are button filters at the top, and then also a text search filter underneath.  Each work individually but how would this be tweaked so that you could use both filter types together?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaVXzQ

Thanks

HTML

```
<div class="button-group filter-button-group">
  <button data-filter="*">show all</button>
  <button data-filter=".metal">metal</button>
  <button data-filter=".transition">transition</button>
  <button data-filter=".alkali, .alkaline-earth">alkali & alkaline-earth</button>
  <button data-filter=":not(.transition)">not transition</button>
  <button data-filter=".metal:not(.transition)">metal but not transition</button>
</div>

<p><input type="text" class="quicksearch" placeholder="Search" /></p>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="element-item transition metal " data-category="transition">
    <h3 class="name">Mercury</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Hg</p>
    <p class="number">80</p>
    <p class="weight">200.59</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item metalloid " data-category="metalloid">
    <h3 class="name">Tellurium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Te</p>
    <p class="number">52</p>
    <p class="weight">127.6</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item post-transition metal " data-category="post-transition">
    <h3 class="name">Bismuth</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Bi</p>
    <p class="number">83</p>
    <p class="weight">208.980</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item post-transition metal " data-category="post-transition">
    <h3 class="name">Lead</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Pb</p>
    <p class="number">82</p>
    <p class="weight">207.2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item transition metal " data-category="transition">
    <h3 class="name">Gold</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Au</p>
    <p class="number">79</p>
    <p class="weight">196.967</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item alkali metal " data-category="alkali">
    <h3 class="name">Potassium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">K</p>
    <p class="number">19</p>
    <p class="weight">39.0983</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item alkali metal " data-category="alkali">
    <h3 class="name">Sodium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Na</p>
    <p class="number">11</p>
    <p class="weight">22.99</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item transition metal " data-category="transition">
    <h3 class="name">Cadmium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Cd</p>
    <p class="number">48</p>
    <p class="weight">112.411</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item alkaline-earth metal " data-category="alkaline-earth">
    <h3 class="name">Calcium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Ca</p>
    <p class="number">20</p>
    <p class="weight">40.078</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item transition metal " data-category="transition">
    <h3 class="name">Rhenium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Re</p>
    <p class="number">75</p>
    <p class="weight">186.207</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item post-transition metal " data-category="post-transition">
    <h3 class="name">Thallium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Tl</p>
    <p class="number">81</p>
    <p class="weight">204.383</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item metalloid " data-category="metalloid">
    <h3 class="name">Antimony</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Sb</p>
    <p class="number">51</p>
    <p class="weight">121.76</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item transition metal " data-category="transition">
    <h3 class="name">Cobalt</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Co</p>
    <p class="number">27</p>
    <p class="weight">58.933</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item lanthanoid metal inner-transition " data-category="lanthanoid">
    <h3 class="name">Ytterbium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Yb</p>
    <p class="number">70</p>
    <p class="weight">173.054</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item noble-gas nonmetal " data-category="noble-gas">
    <h3 class="name">Argon</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Ar</p>
    <p class="number">18</p>
    <p class="weight">39.948</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item diatomic nonmetal " data-category="diatomic">
    <h3 class="name">Nitrogen</h3>
    <p class="symbol">N</p>
    <p class="number">7</p>
    <p class="weight">14.007</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item actinoid metal inner-transition " data-category="actinoid">
    <h3 class="name">Uranium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">U</p>
    <p class="number">92</p>
    <p class="weight">238.029</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item actinoid metal inner-transition " data-category="actinoid">
    <h3 class="name">Plutonium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Pu</p>
    <p class="number">94</p>
    <p class="weight">(244)</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

/* ---- input ---- */

input[type="text"] {
  font-size: 20px;
}

/* ---- isotope ---- */

.grid {
  /*border: 1px solid #333;*/
}

/* clear fix */
.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

/* ---- .element-item ---- */

.element-item {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  /*padding: 10px;*/
  background: #888;
  color: #262524;
}

.element-item > * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.element-item .name {
  position: absolute;

  left: 10px;
  top: 60px;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.element-item .symbol {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 0px;
  font-size: 42px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

.element-item .number {
  position: absolute;
  right: 8px;
  top: 5px;
}

.element-item .weight {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 76px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.element-item.alkali          { background: #F00; background: hsl(   0, 100%, 50%); }
.element-item.alkaline-earth  { background: #F80; background: hsl(  36, 100%, 50%); }
.element-item.lanthanoid      { background: #FF0; background: hsl(  72, 80%, 50%); }
.element-item.actinoid        { background: #0F0; background: hsl( 108, 100%, 50%); }
.element-item.transition      { background: #0F8; background: hsl( 144, 100%, 50%); }
.element-item.post-transition { background: #0FF; background: hsl( 180, 100%, 50%); }
.element-item.metalloid       { background: #08F; background: hsl( 216, 100%, 50%); }
.element-item.diatomic        { background: #00F; background: hsl( 252, 100%, 50%); }
.element-item.halogen         { background: #F0F; background: hsl( 288, 100%, 50%); }
.element-item.noble-gas {
  background: #F08;
  background: hsl( 324, 100%, 50%);
}
```

JS

```
$( function() {
  // quick search regex
  var qsRegex;

  // init Isotope
  var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.element-item',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows',
    filter: function() {
      return qsRegex ? $(this).text().match( qsRegex ) : true;
    }
  });


  // use value of search field to filter
  var $quicksearch = $('.quicksearch').keyup( debounce( function() {
    qsRegex = new RegExp( $quicksearch.val(), 'gi' );
    $grid.isotope();
  }, 200 ) );

});

// debounce so filtering doesn't happen every millisecond
function debounce( fn, threshold ) {
  var timeout;
  return function debounced() {
    if ( timeout ) {
      clearTimeout( timeout );
    }
    function delayed() {
      fn();
      timeout = null;
    }
    timeout = setTimeout( delayed, threshold || 100 );
  }
}


// filter items on button click
$('.filter-button-group').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
  var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
  $('.grid').isotope({ filter: filterValue });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need use `buttonFilter` variable like in this code sample:

```
// quick search regex
var qsRegex;
var buttonFilter;

// init Isotope
var $container = $('.isotope').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.element-item',
  layoutMode: 'fitRows',
  filter: function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var searchResult = qsRegex ? $this.text().match( qsRegex ) : true;
    var buttonResult = buttonFilter ? $this.is( buttonFilter ) : true;
    return searchResult && buttonResult;
  }
});

$('#filters').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
  buttonFilter = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
  $container.isotope();
});

// use value of search field to filter
var $quicksearch = $('#quicksearch').keyup( debounce( function() {
  qsRegex = new RegExp( $quicksearch.val(), 'gi' );
  $container.isotope();
}) );
```

[Example on CodePen](http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/mCdbD)

Comment: This is fantastic!! Thank you so much.